# Enable display manager selection in Red Hat 6 gnome login

Tags: gnome, login, redhat-enterprise-linux, login-screen

We use Red Hat 6 at work and I've a desktop that's a dedicated as my development environment. I routinely use wmii and have NXServer and client running within its own session that allows me to reconnect etc.

I would prefer to "reuse" a "real" desktop session (i.e. shadow mode for nxserver) that will allow me to reconnect, avoiding NXserver/client crashes (which tend to happen) resulting in me losing my nx-session.

My proposed solution therefore is to login on my desktop in wmii and then connect to that display manager session from nxclient (using "shadow" mode). However, when I am presented with the Gnome login screen I cannot seem to find the usual display manager (Gnome, KDE, Wmii, etc) selection dropdown that would allow me to choose wmii.

I have done a lot of searching trying to work out where to configure/enable such an option but have had no luck.

So: how can I enable the display manager selection on the Gnome login screen so I can login to wmii; or what other solutions are there?